# Why does one value in array of ints dereference to random value in c?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, stack, pointer-arithmetic

I'm working on a simple Integer Stack implementation in C, and I define the stack as:

```c
typedef struct {
    int topIndex;
    int totalLength;
    int *elements;
} IntStack;
```

My problem comes when I try to go through each int in `elements` and either access them or pop them off the stack.

My main function is below:

```c
void main() {
    IntStack *mystack = createIntStack(10);
    int temp;

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        push(mystack, i);
    }

    printIntStack(mystack);
    printf("\n");

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        pop(mystack, &temp);
        printf("%d\n", temp);
    }

    destroyIntStack(mystack);
}
```

When I run the program, I push 0 through 9 onto the stack, but when I pop the elements off, one of the values comes back some random large number.
Here's the output:

```
9: 9 - top
8: 8
7: 7
6: 6
5: 5
4: 4
3: 874527284
2: 2
1: 1
0: 0

9
8
7
6
5
4
807406132
2
1
0
```

I cannot figure out why one of the values comes back like this.  When I change the code and create two different `IntStack` variables, the same thing happens to the output, except it's a different number that is randomly changed.

The rest of my implementation code is below (all the stack functions)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STACK_SUCCESS 0
#define STACK_FULL_ERR 1
#define STACK_EMPTY_ERR 2

typedef struct {
    int topIndex;
    int totalLength;
    int *elements;
} IntStack;

IntStack* createIntStack(int length) {
    IntStack *stack = malloc(sizeof(IntStack));
    int *stackElements = malloc(sizeof(int)*length);
    
    stack->topIndex = -1;
    stack->totalLength = length;
    stack->elements = stackElements;

    return stack;
}

void destroyIntStack(IntStack *stack) {
    free(stack->elements);
    free(stack);
}

void printIntStack(IntStack *stack) {
    for (int i=(stack->totalLength-1); i >= 0; i--) {
        if (i < stack->topIndex) {
            // element exists
            printf("%d: %d\n", i, *(stack->elements + sizeof(int)*i));
        } else if (i == stack->topIndex) {
            // element is top of stack
            printf("%d: %d - top\n", i, *(stack->elements + sizeof(int)*i));
        } else {
            // element is null
            printf("%d: NULL\n", i);
        }
    }
}

int push(IntStack *stack, int num) {
    if (stack->topIndex < stack->totalLength-1) {
        stack->topIndex += 1;
        memcpy((stack->elements + sizeof(int)*stack->topIndex), &num, sizeof(int));
        
        return STACK_SUCCESS;
    } else {
        return STACK_FULL_ERR;
    }
}

int pop(IntStack *stack, int *result) {
    if (stack->topIndex != -1) {
        memcpy(result, (stack->elements + sizeof(int)*stack->topIndex), sizeof(int));
        stack->topIndex -= 1;

        return STACK_SUCCESS;
    } else {
        return STACK_EMPTY_ERR;
    }
}
```

Comment: `stack->elements + sizeof(int) * i` and similar is wrong. You need to google how *pointer-arithmetic* works in C. That `sizeof` has no business being there.

Comment: Use `stack->elements[i]` to access the i'th integer in the `elements` array.

Answer (score 2):

You are using incorrectly the pointer arithmetic. For example let's consider the function `push`

```
int push(IntStack *stack, int num) {
    if (stack->topIndex < stack->totalLength-1) {
        stack->topIndex += 1;
        memcpy((stack->elements + sizeof(int)*stack->topIndex), &num, sizeof(int));
        
        return STACK_SUCCESS;
    } else {
        return STACK_FULL_ERR;
    }
}
```

Instead of the expression `stack->elements + sizeof(int)*stack->topIndex` in the call of `memcpy`

```
memcpy((stack->elements + sizeof(int)*stack->topIndex), &num, sizeof(int));
```

you have to write

```
memcpy((stack->elements + stack->topIndex ), &num, sizeof(int));
```

Though it would be much simpler and readable to write

```
stack->elements[stack->topIndex] = num;
```

Such an error is present in other parts of the program as for example here

```
printf("%d: %d\n", i, *(stack->elements + sizeof(int)*i));
```

and so on.

If you have a pointer to an array like

```
int a[2];
int *p = a;
```

then the expression `p + 1`  has a value that is greater than the value stored in `p` by the value `sizeof( int )` So the expression `p + 1` points to the second element of the array `a`.